# NodeJs shows error while installing module in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux

I install nodejs with the help of nvm but after installing it and use add a module in workspace it shows error (not showing error in npm init)

I tried `npx create-next-app` with and without sudo but it isn't working..

So after that i tried making a plain workspace and use npm init it works then i try to install nodemon in it it shows same error. After some time i use `no-bin-links` and it works...

Kindly help please

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! dest /run/media/alokjha/Files/Alok/Websites/my-app/node_modules/.bin/parser
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/run/media/alokjha/Files/Alok/Websites/my-app/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/run/media/alokjha/Files/Alok/Websites/my-app/node_modules/.bin/parser'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/run/media/alokjha/Files/Alok/Websites/my-app/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alokjha/.npm/_logs/2021-12-31T16_04_54_357Z-debug-0.log
```

I use Arch Linux,and bash console..

Comment: Could you detail more ? Have you used `sudo` with your commands ?

Comment: Yes! I tried both Sudo and non-sudo with bash terminal

Comment: What filesystem is `/run/media/alokjha/`? It needs to be filesystem that can handle symlinks. If its e.g. exFAT or NTFS volume it will not work.

Comment: *After some time i use no-bin-links and it works...* Does this means you solved your issue? Or is your question still unanswered?